# Maven no print output when compiling

Tags: java, maven

As I understand it the lifecycle is as follows.

validate
compile
test
package
verify
install
deploy

However when I compile I do not get a print output. The only way seems to be from calling unit tests however I was looking for away to just compile my code as I work and see the output. Would be super grateful if anyone could shed light on this for me.

Thank you

package com.desocial;

```
/**
 * Inside app.java
 */
public final class App {
    private App() {
    }

    /**
     * Says hello to the world.
     * @param args The arguments of the program.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("No print output");
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiling the code does not mean to execute the code. If you like to see the output of your main method I would check in your IDE to run your code (main)?

Comment: You only see code output when you run the code, so first compile, then run the code. If using an IDE, then most have a button to "compile and run" which will take care of both steps so that you can see the output as you make changes to your code.

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you I got it to run by commenting out the package name above

Comment: @sorifiend Thank you I got it to run by commenting out the package name above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [maven exec plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to execute your main class, for example:

`mvn clean compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.desocial.App`

In that case, you will see the output of your code:

```
...
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:java (default-cli) @ app ---
No print output
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response 
Just having some issues getting it working I am getting LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException below is the code I added to pow.xml does this look ok? 

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions><execution>
          <goals><goal>java</goal></goals>
        </execution></executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>org.dhappy.test.NeoTraverse</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

Comment: can you please post the command you are invoking? and what are you trying to achieve? Also the `1.1` is very old (from 2008), the current version of the plugin is `3.0.0`.

In case you want to bind the plugin to a specific phase (for example to run it after `compile` phase), you can use something like:

```
<executions>
 <execution>
  <goals>
   <goal>java</goal>
  </goals>
  <phase>compile</phase>
 </execution>
</executions>
```

inside the plugin configuration. Then your class will be invoked when running `mvn clean compile`